Need Azure Devops Pipeline Logs
I wanted to know that in Azure devops pipeline, if we are running our pipeline in an agent, Does the agent store the logs generated during the pipeline steps somewhere in that machine.
For e.g. We can check the logs in Azure Pipeline UI. But if its stored somewhere in the Agent so that i can use it for my usecase.
I need that logs generated during the pipeline.
I was trying to find any solution to this but i didn't get any reference anything related to this.

Take a good look into Review logs to diagnose pipeline issues

1. Pipeline diagnostic logs
In Azure DevOps, the pipeline diagnostic logs are stored within the Azure DevOps environment itself instead of the agent running the pipeline. Currently, it's not supported to obtain real-time pipeline diagnostic logs locally. If none-real-time logs are ok for you, you can run the following REST API to download it.
GET https://dev.azure.com/{OrgName}/{ProjectName}/_apis/build/builds/{BuildId}/logs?$format=zip&api-version=7.1
2. Worker diagnostic logs
You can get the diagnostic log of the completed build generated by the worker process on the build agent. If you are suing a self-hosted agent, you can see them in your agent's _diag folder.
3. Agent diagnostic logs
Agent diagnostic logs provide a record of how the agent was configured and what happened when it ran. You can also see them in your agent's _diag folder.


Actually my use case is like little different , Because I want the logs to send to Cloudwatch.
In case my pipeline fails i want to send the logs to cloudwatch through the pipeline only ,thats why i was looking for way to retrieve the logs in Agent itself

I am not an expert on AWS Cloudwatch. If you can upload logs to your Cloudwatch using AWS CLI or some commands, there may be a possible workaround for you. You can create a webhook in Azure DevOps and set the trigger as build completed and set "Build Status" to "Failed". Then use "Incoming Webhook" service connection to trigger a new pipeline. In this new pipeline, call the above API to get the logs and use somes scripts to upload to CloudWatch.
